# ¿Como generar un "folio" o numero de entrada de x producto, consecutivo, y que el folio se reinice cada mes ? en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buen día, tengo que generar un numero de entrada , el cual debe ser autoincremental (ejemplo: P1-01-2021), donde P1 es Producto 1(numero autoincremental) y lo demás es el mes y año actual, pero necesito que el numero autoincremental , cada mes se reinicie.

mi duda es como generar la funcion para generar ese numero y el reinicio, lo demas lo puedo concatenar.

pensaba algo así: (modelo).

```
      public static function contadorNumeroEntrada()
    {
        return  Operacion::select(DB::raw("CONCAT('C-'), LPAD(SUBSTR(contador,3)+1 ,'-','date('m')', '-', 
        'date('Y'), as contador "))->where('created_at','=' ,'date(m)')
      ->union()->select(DB::raw("CONCAT('C-'),'-','date('m')','-','date('Y')' as codigo "));

}
```

(codigo del controlador)

```
    //generamos el numero de entrada del contenedor y se le asigna.
        $contenedor = Contenedor::findOrFail($contenedor->idContenedor);
        $contenedor->numeroEntrada = ('C') . Operacion::contadorNumeroEntrada() . date('-m'). date('-Y');
        $contenedor->save();
         redirect()->route('registro.index')->with('success', 'Operacion registrada');
```

antes lo generaba con el id de la operacion.

```
          //generamos el numero de entrada del contenedor y se le asigna.
        $contenedor = Contenedor::findOrFail($contenedor->idContenedor);
        $contenedor->numeroEntrada = ('C') . $contenedor->idContenedor . date('-m'). date('-Y');
        $contenedor->save();
         redirect()->route('registro.index')->with('success', 'Operacion registrada');
```

Comment: Se me ocurre que uses un mutator y en él hagas la validación del mes para reiniciar el campo que estés usando. No sé qué versión de Laravel estás usando, pero en la documentación puede que te guíes mejor en cómo usarlo en tu modelo: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Gracias, fue de gran ayuda lo del mutador, uso Laravel 7 , saludo y gracias.

Comment: @xDnico la respuesta no va en la pregunta, sino en la zona de respuestas por favor edita y corrige

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el comentario del mutador quedo perfecto. Anexo codigo.

```
public function setNumeroEntradaAttribute(){
        $mesActual = date('m');
        $ContadorNumEntMes = Contenedor::select('created_at')->latest()
        ->whereMonth('created_at','=',$mesActual)->take(1)->get();

        $Contador= Contenedor::select('*')
        ->whereMonth('created_at','=',date('m'))->count();

        $autoincremento = 0;
        if($ContadorNumEntMes == true)
        {
          $autoincremento = $Contador;
        }else{

          $ContadorNumEntMes = $mesActual;
          $autoincremento = 1;
        }
        $this->attributes['numeroEntrada'] = 'C'.$autoincremento .date('-m-Y');
    }
```